# PayPal Subscribe button with modify - I am breaking it somehow - how?

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

When I set modify=1 as below and click the button I don't get the advertised behaviour of being taken to a PayPal page where I can upgrade my (the test user's) existing subscription. Instead I just get presented with a new subscription, which doesn't cancel the old one if I agree. I'm sending some extra stuff as well and I figure something there must be breaking it ... but what?

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="subscribe_XXXXXX" id="subscribe_XXXXXX" style="float: left;">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="XXXXXX" />
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="XXXXXX" />
    <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="XXXXXX" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="XXXXXX" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="XXXXXX" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="XXXXXX" />
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXX" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="XXXXXX" />
    <input type="hidden" name="modify" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Subscription options" />
    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="email" />
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Subscription options:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="os0">

                        <option value="Daily">Daily: </option>
                        <option value="Weekly">Weekly:  </option>
                        <option value="Montly">Monthly: </option>
                        <option value="Yearly">Yearly:  </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" title="Subscribe to CognitiveLab ICND1" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" width="96" height="30" /><img alt="|" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

All the URLs are correct and work properly. I've also tried modify=2, and I am setting modify=0 if I know that the user isn't subscribed.

I am expecting this to result in a `subscr_modify` IPN with a revised `period[123]` and `mc_amount[123]` and a `subscr_effective` date. It doesn't, I get a new `subscr_signup.`

Comment: the explanation is not clear, it could be shorter, describing issue itself

Comment: @ses It was clear enough to get an answer and start a most valuable discussion with the people who know what it means. The 'issue itself' is clearly stated as "I don't get the advertised behaviour ..." Really all these unexplained downvotes are a complete and utter travesty of what this site is here for.

Answer (score 14):

Try creating an unhosted button. Some values in the form aren't allow to be used when the preset values are saved within the PayPal account.

When creating the button add the steps below to obtain the "raw" HTML code.

1. Click  "Step 2: Track inventory, profit & loss (optional)"
2. Uncheck "Save button at PayPal"

Once the button is created go ahead and click the link to remove code protection. If the issue continues please post the new form here and I'll take a look.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. I also noticed that setting modify=1 or modify="1" in the final custom variable box wasn't reflected in the generated HTML ... but would it have been saved with the button? At the moment I'm fairly committed to hosted buttons and would prefer to continue along that path if possible.

Comment: If you are creating the button you can add the "modify=1" within the advanced variables box on Step 3. Since these variables are held internally PayPal wouldn't list this field in the form data and there's no need to add it into the HTML form.

Comment: Thanks again. Any chance the restrictions you mention will be documented any time soon?

Comment: You can used a hosted button to modify subscriptions however I couldn't see how the button was created to verify the parameters. 

You can try creating the button again just make sure you are listing the cbt, modify, notify_url and other static values within the variables section on step 3. They will be ignored if passed through the form.

Comment: That's not correct. I am certainly passing notify_url and cbt via the form and in no other manner, and they are certainly not ignored. The fundamental question here is what *are* the 'static values'? You haven't answered that, and neither does the documentation.

Comment: I typically recommend passing all values in the PayPal account to avoid any issues in the future however you are correct. Below are all of the variables that can be passed in the form with hosted buttons.

address_override

address1

address2

cancel_return

cbt

city

cn

country

cs

image_url

invoice

item_name

lc

night_phone_a

night_phone_b

night_phone_c

no_note

notify_url

on

os

page_style

quantity

return

rm

shopping_url

state

undefined_quantity

zip

first_name 

last_name

custom

cpp_header_image

cpp_headerback_color

cpp_headerborder_color

cpp_payflow_color

Comment: All other variables would be static and would have to be entered when creating the button in the PayPal account.

Comment: @PP_MS_Matt Thanks for the information, invaluable. Hope everyone else can find it here :-|